# Using lw on address of $ra

Tags: mips

Assuming we have something of this sort in MIPS

```
    jal F
F:  lw $t1, 0($ra)
    lw $t2, 8($ra)
```

What would we have in $t1 and $t2?

Will $t1 have the instruction code of F??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say X is the address of label F
when jal is called $ra will hold X
you load what is on $ra to $t1 which is the binary machine laguage of the instruction at X
then you load what is 2 words lower (8) which is here not specified in your code, you need to show a 4th line of code to tell you =)

Comment: So what happened when I load what is two words lower? $t2 will only contain half the instruction code of F? And will it contain this in the lower or upper 16 bits? Or will the other 16 bits be provided from the next instruction?

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, I reread what you said and now it all makes sense. Much thanks! :)

Comment: you are most welcome ! just in case others read this: all the 32-bits will be normally loaded into $t2 as any usual 32-bit data